# ASP .Net Core file upload - getting form data when [DisableFormValueModelBinding] attribute is in place

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload

I went ahead and implemented an ASP .Net Core file upload controller per the documentation and it requires using a [DisableFormValueModelBinding] attribute for streaming large files. I got that working fine. Unfortunately, when using that attribute it seems to block my JSON properties coming in from the form.

Is there any way to get both the file and the form data here? Here is my controller code (the request.form calls are where I am having issues):

```cs
[Route("{caseNbr:int}/Document")]
[ResponseType(typeof(CaseDocumentModel))]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostDocument(int caseNbr)
{
    string errorTrackingFileName = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        UserSessionModel userSessionModel = SessionExtensions.CurrentUserSession;

        if (!MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(Request.ContentType))
        {
            return BadRequest("Bad Request");
        }

        var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(Request.ContentType), _defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
        var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);
        var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();



        while (section != null)
        {
            var hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition, out var contentDisposition);

            if (hasContentDispositionHeader)
            {
                if (!MultipartRequestHelper.HasFileContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
                {
                    return BadRequest("Bad Request");
                }

                var fileName = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(contentDisposition.FileName.Value);
                errorTrackingFileName = fileName;
                var trustedFileNameForFileStorage = fileName; //Path.GetRandomFileName();
                var streamedFileContent = await FileHelpers.ProcessStreamedFile(section, contentDisposition, ModelState, _permittedExtensions, _fileSizeLimit);

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Bad Request");
                }

                using (var targetStream = System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(_tempFilePath, trustedFileNameForFileStorage)))
                {
                    await targetStream.WriteAsync(streamedFileContent);

                    **//This is where I am having trouble:**
                    string descrip = HttpContext.Request.Form["Description"].ToString();
                    string docType = HttpContext.Request.Form["DocType"].ToString() ?? "Document";

                    bool isGeneralFileUpload = false;
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Form["GeneralFileUpload"]) == false && AppHelper.IsBool(Request.Form["GeneralFileUpload"]))
                        isGeneralFileUpload = bool.Parse(Request.Form["GeneralFileUpload"]);

                    int transcriptionJobId = 0;
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Form["TranscriptionJobId"]) == false && AppHelper.IsNumeric(Request.Form["TranscriptionJobId"]))
                        transcriptionJobId = int.Parse(Request.Form["TranscriptionJobId"]);

                    CaseDocumentModel createdCaseDocumentModel;

                    if (docType.Equals("Dictation"))
                        createdCaseDocumentModel = DictationRepository.ProcessDictationFile(userSessionModel.DBID, caseNbr, _tempFilePath, fileName, userSessionModel);
                    else if (isGeneralFileUpload)
                        createdCaseDocumentModel = DashboardAdjusterRepository.CreateGeneralFileUploadDocument(_tempFilePath, fileName, userSessionModel, docType, descrip);
                    else if (docType.Equals("Transcription"))
                        createdCaseDocumentModel = TranscriptionRepository.UploadTranscriptionFile(userSessionModel.DBID, _tempFilePath, fileName, userSessionModel, transcriptionJobId);
                    else
                        createdCaseDocumentModel = CaseRepository.CreateCaseDocumentRecord(userSessionModel.DBID, caseNbr, descrip, docType, _tempFilePath, fileName, userSessionModel);

                    return Ok(createdCaseDocumentModel);
                }
            }

            // Drain any remaining section body that hasn't been consumed and
            // read the headers for the next section.
            section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppHelper.WriteErrorLog("CaseController PostDocument failed due to " + ex.Message + " case number was " + caseNbr + " file name was " + errorTrackingFileName);
        return BadRequest("Bad Request");
    }

    return BadRequest("Bad Request");
}
```

Here is a sample call with Postman:

[Screen shot of Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Bj9.jpg)

Comment: Hi @CrystalLake62, what is the version of asp.net core? Did you cannot get the value of `HttpContext.Request.Form["keyname"]`? In my project, it can get the form data by `HttpContext.Request.Form["keyname"]` and get the file by `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files`. Pls check your `HttpContext.Request.Form` if it contains any keys or file.

Comment: I am using .Net Core 5. When I remove the [DisableFormValueModelBinding] attribute, I can read the request.form variables as you described. Unfortunately, that also causes the file upload to fail.

Comment: Hi @CrystalLake62, could you pls share your customize `DisableFormValueModelBinding`?